# Batch directory/folder create with csv

Tags: batch-file, csv, directory

I need to create alot of directories and sub-directories that I need to create from a csv file. I figured using batch would be the easiest way.  I am however not too familiar with batch so I am looking for help.

**Here are some parts of the csv(there are over 800 lines):**

```
FolderID,FolderName,FolderParentID,OwnerID,TopLevelFolderID
1,My Folder,NULL,1,1
2,My Folder,NULL,2,2
5,Test,NULL,3,5
195,My Folder,NULL,132,195
174,My Folder,NULL,133,174
133,My Folder,NULL,135,133
154,My Folder,NULL,139,154
134,My Folder,NULL,140,134
137,My Folder,NULL,141,137
136,My Folder,NULL,145,136
191,My Folder,NULL,148,191
160,My Folder,NULL,150,160
147,My Folder,NULL,152,147
165,My Folder,NULL,153,165
157,My Folder,NULL,154,157
158,My Folder,NULL,155,158
142,My Folder,NULL,157,142
192,My Folder,NULL,158,192
153,My Folder,NULL,159,153
186,My Folder,NULL,160,186
177,My Folder,NULL,162,177
```

**I thought through it and this is basically how the structure should be:**

```
Create Folder 1 per OwnerID with OwnerID as folder name
"/OwnerID/"


if FolderParentID = NULL and/or is same as TopLevelFolderID, then create folder with        FolderID in OwnerID folder.
"/OwnerID/FolderID/"



if FolderParentID = notNULL, and FolderParentID is same as TopLevelFolderID, then create folder with FolderID in FolderParentID
"/OwnerID/FolderParentID/FolderID/"


if FolderParentID = notNULL, adn FolderParentID is not same as TopLevelFolderID, then create folder with FolderID in FolderID form level above
"/OwnerID/FolderParentID/FolderID/FolderID/"
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!!**

format edited..
[google.com](http://google.com)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1-5delims=," %%a IN (q20592270.txt) DO (
  ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%d"   
)
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1-5delims=," %%a IN (q20592270.txt) DO (
  IF "%%c"=="NULL" ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%d\%%a"   
  IF "%%c"=="%%e" ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%d\%%a"   
)
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1-5delims=," %%a IN (q20592270.txt) DO (
  IF NOT "%%c"=="NULL" IF "%%c"=="%%e" ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%d\%%c\%%a"   
)
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=1-5delims=," %%a IN (q20592270.txt) DO (
  IF NOT "%%c"=="NULL" IF NOT "%%c"=="%%e" ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%d\%%c\%%a\%%a"   
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should create the directories required. Obviously, you'd need to specify the destination.

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change each `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories.

Note that when an attempt is made to create a directory that already exists, an error message will be displayed. This is harmless but ugly. You can cause the error message to be suppressed by appending `2>nul` to each `MD ...` line.

`q20592270.txt` is simply the name of the file I used for your test data (which always has the third field "NULL"). You would need to substitute the name of you .csv file.

I'm presuming that the data actually contains the word "NULL", it is not simply an empty field.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize the variable that store field names
set "fieldNames="

rem Process the csv file
for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%a in (theFile.csv) do (

   rem Get field names from first line
   if not defined fieldNames (
      set "fieldNames=%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e"
   ) else (

      rem Copy field values to field names
      for /F "tokens=1-5" %%i in ("!fieldNames!") do (
         set "%%i=%%a" & set "%%j=%%b" & set "%%k=%%c" & set "%%l=%%d" & set "%%m=%%e"
      )

      rem Create Folder 1 per OwnerID with OwnerID as folder name
      ECHO md "\!OwnerID!"

      rem if FolderParentID = NULL and/or is same as TopLevelFolderID, then create folder with        FolderID in OwnerID folder.
      if !FolderParentID! equ NULL ECHO md "\!OwnerID!\!FolderID!"
      if !FolderParentID! equ !TopLevelFolderID! ECHO md "\!OwnerID!\!FolderID!"

      rem if FolderParentID = notNULL, and FolderParentID is same as TopLevelFolderID, then create folder with FolderID in FolderParentID
      if !FolderParentID! neq NULL if !FolderParentID! equ !TopLevelFolderID! ECHO md "\!OwnerID!\!FolderParentID!\!FolderID!"

      rem if FolderParentID = notNULL, adn FolderParentID is not same as TopLevelFolderID, then create folder with FolderID in FolderID form level above
      if !FolderParentID! neq NULL if !FolderParentID! neq !TopLevelFolderID! ECHO md "\!OwnerID!\!FolderParentID!\!FolderID!\!FolderID!"

      echo -------------------------------------

   )

)
```

Output example:

```
md "\1"
md "\1\1"
-------------------------------------
md "\2"
md "\2\2"
-------------------------------------
md "\3"
md "\3\5"
-------------------------------------
md "\132"
md "\132\195"
-------------------------------------
md "\133"
md "\133\174"
-------------------------------------
md "\135"
md "\135\133"
```